# Code 141 success/error message not called on parse cloud code nested query

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform, cloud, parse-cloud-code

I keep receiving a code 141 error success/error was not called. I am running another function getCinemasInLocation which returns a JSON like: {result: [result1, result2]}. I want to iterate over this array and run a query each time the loop runs and all the results to an array. That is, the results of all oteration will be in an array. Am I doing it right?

```
//This function uses getCinemasInLocation to retrieve the movie objects that are showing in the cinemas
Parse.Cloud.define("getMovieIdsInCinemas", function(request, response) {
    var cinemasInLocaton = [];
    var theLocation = request.params.theLocation;
    cinemasInLocation = Parse.Cloud.run("getCinemasInLocation", {theLocation: theLocation});
    for (i = 0; i < cinemasInLocation.length; i++){
        var query = new Parse.Query("showing");
        var movieIds = [];
        query.equalTo("cinema", {
            __type: "Pointer",
            className: "Cinema",
            objectId: cinemasInLocation[i]
        });
        query.find({
            success: function(results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    movieIds.push(results[i].get("movie"));
                }

            response.success(movieIds);
            },
            error: function() {
                response.error("movie lookup failed 2");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This is the getCinemasInLocation that does not work

```
function getCinemasInLocation(theLocation) {
// some code
//var result = ["xiUXXYFhAl","Yanh9iDykk"];
//return result;

   var result = new Parse.Promise();
   var query = new Parse.Query("Cinema");
   query.equalTo("Location", theLocation);

    query.find({
        success: function(objects) {
            var cinemas = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
                var cinema = objects[i];
                cinemas.push(cinema.id);
            }
            result.resolve(cinemas);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            result.reject(error);
        }
    });

return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Parse.Cloud.run doesn't return an array. It returns a Promise. So, create a normal javascript function in the same file: getCinemasInLocation()
2. As @Delhi said, you can only call response.success() or response.error() once. So, don't put them in a loop.
3. Use Promises on parallel. So, let's use the loop of Underscore instead of the normal FOR loop. You can start multiple operations at once, and use Parse.Promise.when to create a new promise that will be resolved when all of its input promises is resolved. You can read more about this in the documentation: https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises-parallel

```
var _ = require('underscore');
```

function getCinemasInLocation(theLocation) {
    // some code
    var result = [id1, id2];
    return result;
}
// This function returns the array of movieIds of a cinema
function getMovieIdsInCinema(cinemaId) {
    var result = new Parse.Promise();
    var query = new Parse.Query("showing");
    query.equalTo("cinema", {
        __type: "Pointer",
        className: "Cinema",
        objectId: cinemaId
    });
    query.find({
        success: function(objects) {
            var movieIds = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
                var movie = objects[i].get("movie");
                movieIds.push(movie.id);
            }
            result.resolve(movieIds);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            result.reject(error);
        }
    });
    return result;
}
Parse.Cloud.define("getMovieIdsInCinemas", function(request, response) {
    var cinemasInLocation = [];
    var theLocation = request.params.theLocation;
    cinemasInLocation = getCinemasInLocation(theLocation);

    var promises = [];
    _.each(cinemasInLocation, function(cinemaId) {
        promises.push(getMovieIdsInCinema(cinemaId));
    });

    Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(
        function() {
            var result = [];
            _.each(arguments, function(object) {
                result.push(object); // each object is an array of movieIds
            });
            response.success(result); // return array of arrays
        },
        function(error) {
            response.error(error);
        }
    );
});

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked perfectly. I edited the getCinemasinLocation function to retrieve the cinemas from the database and then it returns a null array. I will post the edit above. I replicated the getMovieIdsInCinema() in doing it, and it still does not work